# Postgresql 11 - Order by integer array index

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, sql-order-by, postgresql-11

I want to list my products in the database according to their id order in the array

My array

```
'{3,2,1}'::int[]
```

For example

```
SELECT id FROM product WHERE id = ANY ('{3,2,1}'::int[]);
```

This query gets the products with ordered by product id

```
|id|
|1 |
|2 |
|3 |
```

But i want to list my products ordered by index of the array ids. Like this :

```
|id|
|3 |
|2 |
|1 |
```

Is it possible to do this ? How can i do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `array_position()`:

```
ORDER BY array_position('{3,2,1}'::int[], id)
```

If you didn't want to repeat the array twice:

```
select p.id
from product p join
     (values ('{3,2,1}'::int[])) v(ar)
     on p.id = any(v.ar)
order by array_position(v.ar, p.id);
```

Comment: Note that this method doesn't work if your array is unsorted and contains duplicate values. For example, `[1, 2, 1]` would get ordered as `[1, 1, 2]`.

Answer (score 5):

You can `unnest()` the array with option `WITH ORDINALITY` to keep track of the index of each element, join it with the table and use the index as `ORDER BY` criteria:

```
SELECT p.id
FROM product AS p
INNER JOIN unnest('{3,2,1}'::int[]) WITH ORDINALITY AS a(id, nr) 
    ON p.id = a.id
ORDER BY a.nr;
```